# How to set up LAMP server on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I am a newbie to Ubuntu. I have a dual-booting Windows laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 already installed. Being a newbie, I messed around with installing LAMP server. I am lost in Linux's Terminal Command Land (TCL). Please help!

Comment: Welcome. See the ubuntu documentation - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP is a great start.

Comment: [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I see nothing for me to answer; no error, no warning. "I am lost in Linux's Terminal " So go google about it ;-) You can't expect us to tell you how command line works... after 20+ years I am still learning new stuff about command line :D

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install lamp-server^
sudo apt install phpmyadmin -y
```

Comment: What do you mean when recommend use this steps: "2. sudo apt-install", "4. apt-get install"?

Comment: same,, iam sory, was edited